# Mongodb, should a number fields be indexed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

I'm trying to get a proper understanding of using mongodb to optimise queries. In this case it's for fields that would hold an integer. So say i have a collection
with two fields `value` and `cid` where value will store data of type string and `cid` will store data of type number.

I intend to write queries that will search for records by matching the fields `value` and `cid`. Also the expectation is that the saved records for this collection would get very large and hence queries could benefit from mongodb indexes. It makes sense to me to index the `value` field which holds string. But I wonder if the `cid` field requires indexing, or its okay as is, given that it will be holding integers.

I'm asking because I was going through a code base with this exact scenario described and i can't figure out why the number field was not indexed. Hoping my question makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of datatypes, generally speaking all queries should use an index.  If you use a sort predicate you can assist the database by having a compound index on both the equality portion of the query (the filter predicate) as well as the sorting portion (the sort predicate).  MongoDB recommends following the index strategy referred to as the E.S.R. rule - see [Performance Best Practices](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) for E.S.R. rule.